# C language - how to create PostScript file

Tags: c, postscript

How can I create a PS (PostScript) file in C language?

For example, I want create file myfile.ps and *draw* to PostScript this code:

```
%!
newpath
0 0 moveto
120 120 lineto
144 120 lineto
200 122 lineto
0 0 lineto
stroke 
showpage
```

Comment: Have you tried pslib? http://pslib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: No, I'm a beginner, i will try it, thank you.

Comment: this example doesn't require any library, you can do with quite straightforward file operations in c --  so what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally postscript is just ascii text, so the standard text-output facilities will work just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *outfile;
    outfile = fopen("myfile.ps", "w");
    fprintf(outfile,
        "%%!\n"
        "%d %d moveto\n"
        "%d %d lineto\n"
        "%d %d lineto\n"
        "%d %d lineto\n"
        "%d %d lineto\n"
        "stroke\n"
        "showpage\n",
        0, 0,
        120, 120,
        144, 120,
        200, 122,
        0, 0
    );
    return 0;
}
```